# Login with php and save users unique id

Tags: php, facebook, openid, smarty

I have a website in which I am supposed to implement open Id . I am using smarty . Now I am totally messed up how to keep record of the user or to create session for the user since templates are htm file in my case

and in the facebook example we used php files to extract data of the user (http://excoflare.com/dev2011/socialnetwork/index.php?menu=openid&cmd=fb)

This is what I want :

1. login using facebook ids
2. save useer unique id to database

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Please post the codes.

Comment: Also, localhost-links won't be working 99% of the time, as people either 1) don't have a web-server installed or 2) don't have the same file-structure and files as you do.

Comment: I think codes will be too lengthy . Because it includes templates,php files . Please check my link

Comment: M so sorry for giving wrong url....I updated the URL

Comment: Can you post the code ? Have you follow this step : http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/), you will find examples of how to get user data using the api. Or you will be able to get the user data by using

```
$userData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$accessToken)); 
var_dump($userData);
```